# how to download larger binary object from postgres using nodejs express?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, largeobject

I have node js rest api script to query from Postgres tables. It's working fine, but When I try to fetch a large objects using "lo_get" of Postgres, I get

> JavaScript heap out of memory

Below is the toy example.

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 8000
var controller= require('./src/controller');

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)

app.use('/cont', controller);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

controller.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/fileID/:lo_oid/', function( req, res) {
    const lo_oid =  parseInt(req.params.lo_oid)
    model.exportLoSaint(lo_oid, function (err, object) {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
   #  Fixed the typo
   #     response.status(200).file(file);
        res.status(200).objects;
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Model.js

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
var exportLoSaintQuery= "SELECT lo_get($1)"

const exportLoSaint = (lo_oid, callback) => {
    pool.query( exportLoSaintQuery ,[lo_oid], (error, results) => {
                if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                }
                else {
                    callback(results.rows)
                }
            })
        }
```

on sending request .. `http://ipaddress:8000/cont/fileID/<fileID>/` getting below error.

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1b2cbd65be1d]
Security context: 0x2bf3bbc08bd9 <JSObject>
    1: toJSON [0x259ded584f29] [buffer.js:~979] [pc=0x1b2cbd665145](this=0x306d2be17731 <Uint8Array map = 0x9dd44699a69>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->0
    3: InternalFrame [pc: 0x1b2cbd60ee75]
    4: EntryFrame [pc: 0x1b2cbd6092c1]
    5: builtin exit frame: stringify(this=0x0a6855c58f61 <Object map = 0x428c84042a9>,0x2160e26026f1 <undefined>,0x2160e...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x56228da912e4 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x56228da91332  [node]
 3: 0x56228dc86d4a v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0x56228dc86fc5 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0x56228e0387d6  [node]
 6: 0x56228e04e018 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 7: 0x56228e01a63b v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 8: 0x56228e01aad8 v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Heap::RootListIndex, int, v8::internal::Object*, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 9: 0x56228dfe48fe  [node]
10: 0x56228dfe4ad3  [node]
11: 0x56228e143566 v8::internal::JSObject::AddDataElement(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::ShouldThrow) [node]
12: 0x56228e17897e v8::internal::Object::SetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::LanguageMode, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [node]
13: 0x56228e2c1299 v8::internal::Runtime::SetObjectProperty(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::LanguageMode) [node]
14: 0x56228e0a9b45 v8::internal::Runtime_KeyedStoreIC_Slow(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
15: 0x1b2cbd65be1d
```

The size of binary object in postgres is only 128 mb. So, I increased the size of node js to 1gb, it did not help. Other solution I found was not using express to download binary from postgres.

******************* **update 1** *********** ************

Model.js

```
const exportLoSaintForMaster = (oid, fileName, callback) => {
    var fileStream = require('fs').createWriteStream(fileName);
    var man = new LargeObjectManager({ pg: pool });
    pool.query('BEGIN', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            pool.emit('error', err);
        }
        console.log("\nthe oid : %d\n", oid)
        var bufferSize = 16384;
        man.openAndReadableStream(oid, bufferSize, function (err, size, stream) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                return console.error('Unable to read the given large object', err);
            }

            console.log('Streaming a large object with a total size of', size);
            stream.on('end', function () {
                pool.query('COMMIT', callback);
            });

            // Store it as an image

            stream.pipe(fileStream);
        });
    });
    callback(fileStream)
};
```

<strike>The scripts waits for a long time and then error outs with the below message ..</strike>

```
        response.status(200).objects;
        ^

ReferenceError: response is not defined
```

******************* **Update 2** *********************

After fixing the typo above error is no more.
yet I see some problems.. as the client-side is not able to download it. it shows below error on client side ..

i tried to do get . I get below message

```
{"_writableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,"finalCalled":false,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"destroyed":false,"decodeStrings":true,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":0,"writing":false,"corked":0,"sync":true,"bufferProcessing":false,"writecb":null,"writelen":0,"bufferedRequest":null,"lastBufferedRequest":null,"pendingcb":0,"prefinished":false,"errorEmitted":false,"emitClose":false,"autoDestroy":false,"bufferedRequestCount":0,"corkedRequestsFree":{"next":null,"entry":null}},"writable":true,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0,"path":"myfile1","fd":null,"flags":"w","mode":438,"autoClose":true,"bytesWritten":0,"closed":false}
```

I am using a postman to download it. I think the issue may be because of the way controller.js is invoking the script in model.js .

Please suggest me

******************* **Update 3** ****************

controller.js

```
router.get('/fileID/:lo_oid/fileName/:fileName', function (req, res) {
    const oid = parseInt(req.params.lo_oid)
    const fileName = req.params.fileName
    model.exportLoSaintForMaster(oid,fileName, (err, stream) => stream.pipe(res));
});
```

model.js

```
const exportLoSaintForMaster = (oid, fileName, callback) => {
    var fileStream = require('fs').createWriteStream(fileName);
    var man = new LargeObjectManager({ pg: pool });
    pool.query('BEGIN', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            pool.emit('error', err);
        }
        console.log("\nthe oid : %d\n", oid)
        var bufferSize = 16384;
        man.openAndReadableStream(oid, bufferSize, function (err, size, stream) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                return console.error('Unable to read the given large object', err);
            }

            console.log('Streaming a large object with a total size of', size);
            stream.on('end', function () {
                pool.query('COMMIT', callback);
            });

            // Store it as an image

            stream.pipe(fileStream);
        });
    });
    callback(null, fileStream)
}; 

module.exports = {

    exportLoSaintForMaster
}
```

getting below error

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_CANNOT_PIPE]: Cannot pipe, not readable
    at WriteStream.Writable.pipe (_stream_writable.js:243:24)
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Have you tried using nodejs stream?

Comment: No. I let me try out that option..

Comment: According to your code, you're piping your stream to a file on your filesystem instead of piping it to the client via the express response object

Comment: please see the updated code..

Comment: `callback(null, stream)` and then `exportLoSaintForMaster(oid, fileName, (err, stream) => steam.pipe(res))`. Also, fileName is not needed here.

Comment: Now i am getting another error.
I am sorry ... if i m doing some silly mistake .. I am new to node js. 
Could you please look into "update 3 " section.

Comment: I've editied my answer, also the whole thing would be cleaner using promises, but that's not really the point here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've mentioned you could increase NodeJS heap size witht the flag `-max-old-space-size`, for example set it to 4GB :

```
 node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js
```

But **it's not a proper solution**. The right thing to do would be to handle it with streams as  *Aviv Lo* mentioned it in the comment. It will allow you to reduce the memory footprint of your script by handling data chunk by chunk.

For handling PostgreSQL Large Objects, you can use [node-pg-large-objects](https://github.com/Joris-van-der-Wel/node-pg-large-object) (`npm i -s pg-large-object`) :

```
const { LargeObjectManager } = require('pg-large-object');
const { createWriteStream } = require('fs');

router.get('/fileID/:lo_oid/', (req, res, next) => {

    // assuming db is your Database connection
    // When working with Large Objects, always use a transaction                                                                                                                                              
    db.tx(tx => {
        const man = new LargeObjectManager({pgPromise: tx});
        const lo_oid = parseInt(req.params.lo_oid);

        const bufferSize = 16384; // the size of each chunk, customize it                                                                                                                                                                     

        return man.openAndReadableStreamAsync(oid, bufferSize)
            .then(([size, stream]) => {
                stream.pipe(res); // It will take care of binding to data and end events.                                                                                                                                                     
            });
    }).catch(error => {
        next(error); // pass to express error handler                                                                                                                                                                                         
    });

}
```

This way you will handle your large object as a stream and pipe it to your client for download.

With this solution, the maximum heap size occupied by **this part** of your script would be the `bufferSize` and not the whole file size as previously.

---

### Update 3 edit

In your controller :

```
router.get('/fileID/:lo_oid/fileName/:fileName', function (req, res, next) {
    const oid = parseInt(req.params.lo_oid);
    const fileName = req.params.fileName;
    res.header('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`);

    model.exportLoSaintForMaster(oid, (err, stream) => { 
        if (err) return next(err);
        stream.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

In your model :

```
const exportLoSaintForMaster = (oid, callback) => {
    const man = new LargeObjectManager({ pg: pool });
    pool.query('BEGIN', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            pool.emit('error', err);
        }
        console.log("\nthe oid : %d\n", oid)
        const bufferSize = 16384;
        man.openAndReadableStream(oid, bufferSize, function (err, size, stream) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            console.log(`Streaming a large object with a total size of ${size}`);
            stream.on('end', _ => pool.query('COMMIT'));

            callback(null, stream);
        });
    });
};
```

Warning : I don't know how your `pool` object works, so this code may not work exactly as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I tried to implement the solution. But I am getting error as "ERROR: Could not export large object oid '531978', error: HTTP::Response=HASH(0x56537fca91a0) " To let you know, the size of the object is 100m b approx

Comment: I noticed that files are getting downloaded on the server where the node js script is running ..

Comment: `response is not defined` just means that their is not variable in your scope named `response`, maybe you've mistaken the name of your variable. 
Do you have your code on a git to share it ?

Comment: yeah that was a typo , I fixed it .. but as i stated above its not getting downloaded on the client side.

Comment: Do you have any errors on the server-side app or do you have something in the Chrome console or the network tab ?

Comment: After fixing the typo above error is no more. yet I see some problems.. as the client-side is not able to download it. it shows below error on client side ..

Error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)

I am using a postman to download it. I think the issue may be because of the way controller.js is invoking the script in model.js .

Answer (score 0):

to resolve `response is not defined` you have to change `response` to `res` in `controller.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/fileID/:lo_oid/', function(req, res) {
    const lo_oid =  parseInt(req.params.lo_oid)
    model.exportLoSaint(lo_oid, function (err, file) {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        res.status(200).file(file);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: yeah that was a typo , I fixed it .. but as i stated above its not getting downloaded on the client side.